# Multiple text replacement tools for Linux?

Tags: software-recommendation

I need a tool that can replace multiple expressions by others on a single text or text file. This is because I have to "translate" templates that have the same function from one wiki to another.

I found a tool online that does this (link  below), but it is limited to 50 items at a time, and I actually need to replace much more than that. I also need to save the list of replacements so I can re-use it regularly instead of having to rewrite it every time.
https://www.joydeepdeb.com/tools/find-replace.html

gedit also does this with the "Replace all" function, but only one expression at a time, which is useless to my task because, as I said, I need to replace far more than that.

If anyone knows about any Linux software or online tool that does this, it will be extremely helpful.

Comment: You haven't provided any example input/ouput, but sounds like you want `sed`.

Comment: Do you want to perform in-place-edits, or write translated files into new files, leaving originals unaltered? Command-line-tools `sed` , `awk` and `perl` have many command-line options such as `-i` for that. `-i` would perform in-place-edit, for instance

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[`sed`](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/man1/sed.1.html) is a stream editor for filtering and transforming text ... The find and replace command syntax looks like `s/find/replace/` where `find` is either a string or a regular expression and `replace` is not a regular expression and is, mostly(*apart from a few `sed` place holders and modifiers*), a string ... that command can be used on the command line between `' ... '` or `" ...  "` like so(*`textfile` is the file containing text to be found and replaced*):

```
sed 's/find/replace/' textfile
```

Multiple commands can be nested with the option `-e` like so:

```
sed -e 's/find1/replace1/' -e 's/find2/replace2/' -e 's/find3/replace3/' textfile
```

`sed` commands can, also, be used from a script file(*one command per line*) with the script file looking like this:

```
s/find1/replace1/
s/find2/replace2/
s/find3/replace3/
```

And that script file is called by the `-f` option like so:

```
sed -f scriptfile textfile
```

**Notice** that `sed` will not edit/modify the original file i.e. `textfile` unless you provide the in-place editing option `-i` on the command line like so:

```
sed -i 's/find/replace/' textfile
```

`sed` is mainly a command-line tool that is used in the terminal.

However, an on-line implementation of the GNU `sed` is available at [sed.js.org](https://sed.js.org/)

Comment: Let's suppose that file.txt says the following:
"I eat red apples, salty cookies, and hot milk."

I want to replace these three by different foods, so I open a .txt file and type the following:

s/"red apples"/"green apples"/
s/"salty cookies"/"sweet cakes"/
s/"hot milk"/"ice tea"/

I save the file as script.sed, open the terminal in the directory where both the file and script are and type the following:
 
sed -i -f script.sed file.txt

It does NOT work. It doesn't replace the items as I requested. I've tried saving the script as .sh too but still doesn't work. What should I do?

Comment: @AnvosGorbs Remove all quotes `”` e.g. `s/red apples/green apples/` and put each command on a separate new line and it will work

Comment: @AnvosGorbs everything between the first `/` and second `/` will be matched exactly … So you must not quote that string and if you want to match a literal `”` that exists in the text file then you need to escape every occurrence of it like so `\”`

Comment: Thanks! That helped me a lot.