# grep command to get file list with concatenated custom text

Tags: command-line, text-processing, grep, xargs

I am trying to list of files' names with custom text(my another command) with it. I am using below command:

```
grep -rl --include=*.php --include=*.html --include=*.js 'ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js' httpdocs/test/ | 
    xargs echo "sed -i 's~ajax.googleapis.com\/ajax\/libs\/jquery\/3.6.0\/jquery.min.js~example.com\/js\/included\/jquery3_6.min.js~g';" {} \; >> list_js_sed.txt
```

Above command executing fine, without any error and creating a file 'list_js_sed.txt' with below text:

```
sed -i 's~ajax.googleapis.com\/ajax\/libs\/jquery\/3.6.0\/jquery.min.js~example.com\/js\/included\/jquery3_6.min.js~g'; {} ; httpdocs/test/ssi/ss/test1.html httpdocs/test/ssi/test2.html httpdocs/test/test_ss.php
```

But I want result to be like:

```
sed -i 's~ajax.googleapis.com\/ajax\/libs\/jquery\/3.6.0\/jquery.min.js~example.com\/js\/included\/jquery3_6.min.js~g' httpdocs/test/ssi/ss/test1.html;
sed -i 's~ajax.googleapis.com\/ajax\/libs\/jquery\/3.6.0\/jquery.min.js~example.com\/js\/included\/jquery3_6.min.js~g' httpdocs/test/ssi/test2.html;
sed -i 's~ajax.googleapis.com\/ajax\/libs\/jquery\/3.6.0\/jquery.min.js~example.com\/js\/included\/jquery3_6.min.js~g' httpdocs/test/test_ss.php;
```

Please help me to fix this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`\;` is not needed with `xargs` ... The place holder `{}` is not set, so not used as expected but used as a literal string instead ... So you could use:

```
grep -rl --include=*.php --include=*.html --include=*.js 'ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js' httpdocs/test/ | xargs -I {} echo "sed -i 's~ajax.googleapis.com\/ajax\/libs\/jquery\/3.6.0\/jquery.min.js~example.com\/js\/included\/jquery3_6.min.js~g' {};" >> list_js_sed.txt
```

---

As a side note … Two things(*not critical but worth mentioning*):

- In the match or replace strings, `/` needs to be escaped with a backslash `\/` **only** if it’s also used as the delimiter … Which is clearly not the case in your example as the delimiter used is `~` … That is covered with a bit more detail in [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1422283).
- Multiple `sed` commands can be nested in one script for performance reasons … That is covered with detail in [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1421728).

Comment: Thanks, it works for me ...

Comment: Can you please explain what is meaning of this `xargs -I {}` and '{};' in echo command

Comment: @Atul `xargs -I {}` sets `{}`(*you can choose a different place holder if you want*) as the place-holder/representative of the output from `grep` that `xargs` reads from the pipe `|` and passes to the `echo` command as arguments so you can choose where that output is placed by putting the place-holder `{}` where you want.

Comment: Thanks @Raffa for the explanation.. really helpful

Comment: Why are you escaping the `/`? You're using `~` as the delimiter here, so the `/` don't need to be escaped.

Comment: @terdon That’s a legitimate question for @Atul … As far as I was concerned answering the OP, this was just a string not a `sed` command … Yes, it might be used later, but that’s a different matter and escaping `/`, although not needed, wouldn’t harm … If I were to choose I would have nested all the commands in one `sed` script as well … But, I was hesitant as to whether I should widen the scope of the OP to cover, probably, irrelevant matters … That’s what I was thinking … But, the point is made clear now … Thanks to you :-)

Comment: @terdon You made me do it anyway … :-)

Comment: lol, :) Well, it makes for an even better answer!